# Angular Constant for Service injected into Module

Tags: angularjs, service, dependency-injection, constants

I'm creating a packaged service to be included by various in-house apps. The service has two values that need to be set before the service can run properly.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myService']);
```

So I thought to add a .js file with:

```
angular.constant('myKey','12345');
```

..and then in my service:

```
angular.service('myService', function(myKey)
{
});
```

But it seems you can't define a constant separately from module...so I did this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myService'])
  .constant('myKey','12345');
```

..but that doesn't work either, because the constant doesn't exist when injecting myService.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with your first fix.

```
angular.module('myApp').constant('myKey', '12345');
```

A constant is a provider, and can be thought of in the same vein as service/factory/etc and created with the same syntax.